# How can we display product based on more than one select attribute?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, filter

I am new in Magento i want to filter product on the basis of attribute such as
year, make, model so how can it will done.

on home page i call one template file i.e filter.phtml

In this file i create simple form for filter product from its attribute
 year: to get year i call block method 
`$this->getYear()` in year dropdown list. like wise for model and make.
On form action i called controller as
`Mage::getUrl('ymm/index/filter')`. So now i am getting post data in block using
`getRequest()->getPost() or getParam()` mothod.
 So now my question is how can we filter product on the basis of post data attribute?

Thanks for reply...........

Answer (score 2):

Use addAttributeToFilter

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

hope this helps

Comment: Your answer should contain more detail.